# Query within results from a previous query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

How do I query within the results that have come from a previous MySQL query?

I want to avoid nested SELECTs if I can, but only out of personal preference.

Comment: Use the WHERE statement to filter your search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the result of the first query in a [temporary table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), query from that, then drop the temp table.